# How to configure stepping-into Rails's core with Vim Exuberant Tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, ide, ctags

While enjoying the flexibility of Vim Exuberant Tags `def` navigation in Rails applications, I thought why not go deeper, and have the Rails core source as a low-level reference.

How can I configure Vim to include another tag file, and what code should I map?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply pass your gems directory on the command line the ctags command. ctags takes a list of source files to examine on the command line. For instance if I was using rails 2.3.5 and running ctags from the root of my Rails application:

```
ctags -R $GEM_HOME/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/* ./*
```

If you are using bundler, you could use `bundle show` to find the path for you. ctags will also let you exclude certain directories using the `--exclude` flag. Check out the [options documentation](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html#OPTIONS) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Vim looks for its tag files in the `'tags'` option, which is a list of (absolute/relative) paths. Sou in Vim you could do

```
:set tags+=/path/to/ror/tags
```

Also see

```
:help 'tags'
```